Android.bp support required for precompiled .so in System/lib64 and vendor/lib64
I have few precompiled .so files downloaded from one build system into another one, which is required to be pushed as part of System/lib64 and vendor/lib64 for application to work. I am trying to add it in the Android.bp as,
  // system/lib64 | vendor/lib64
  cc_prebuilt_library_shared {
    name: "libTestTransport",
    vendor_available: true,
        product_available: true,
        srcs: ["lib64/libTestTransport.so"],
        installable: true,
    }
    
    cc_prebuilt_library_shared {
        name: "libtestchip",
        vendor_available: true,
        product_available: true,
        srcs: ["lib64/libtestchip.so"],
        installable: true,
    }

All changes are build and flashed. However after checking through the adb shell, only  system/lib64 partition is able to see all the binaries but nothing in the vendor/lib64. Tried few other combinations as,
//which is exclusive for vendor/lib64. In this case system/lib64 failed. 
vendor: true, 

Any help would be appreciated.
